# How do I actually remove my account?

Tags: support

I've seen some people vanish from rpg.stackexchange.com so I assume there's a way to delete the account, but I can't seem to find said mechanism.  Note, I only want to remove from rpg, not from the whole stackexchange/stackoverflow/et al suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I or any mod can delete you, if you're set on it. But I would recommend not deleting, because you may not be able to come back later.  What's wrong with just "wandering away" if you're not currently interested?

Comment: I firmly believe in voting with my feet.  It is increasingly clear to me that there is no a) ability nor b) desire to attempt to bring this site out of the realm of essentially being just a redundant site to get questions about D&D4 answered.  (Why redundant?  There's about 4 billion D&D4-oriented sites out there already.)  I have other sites I can go to for RPG-oriented questions and/or discussion, so this site, which doesn't cater to my tastes and which doesn't show signs of **wanting** to do so (not that it should!) is not for me.  I'd rather not clutter the database unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, I personally hate 4e and want the site to do more, but I do regard this as a weird "waaah, I'm taking my ball and going home" move that is certainly counterproductive to that goal.  You'll still be "cluttering the database," as your content will not be removed and there will thus be an "anon" user placeholder where you used to be.  But, if you want to be deleted, tell me and I'll do it.

Comment: I think @mxyzplk is being too inflammatory, but I agree with his point. If you need to take some time off from the site, do it. If you want to put some energy into encouraging questions about other games (I'd love that), do that too. But deleting your account is rather too dramatic.

Comment: +1 to @mxyzplk and @Graham - If you'd like to see this site become more than what it is, stick around and help that happen.  I'd love to help you myself, but I currently have no experience in - nor time to devote to - other systems.  I imagine that is also the case for the majority of users here, which has led to the current situation.  Nobody's objecting to the site being more than a D&D4e Q&A site - they mostly just don't have the resources and/or experience to do much about it.  It helps nothing for the few who are so equipped to just up and leave.

Comment: @Iszi - There's been a lot of that "you should be the change you want to see" advice here. But if there's a continued opposition to changes, it's not unreasonable to say that one intends to invest their energies elsewhere. If @JUST MY correct OPINION is at that point, I think deleting his account serves the community more than disappearing would, as it brings more awareness and visibility to the issues which are alienating users. The community needs to realize it helps nothing for the few who are so equipped to be alienated.

Comment: @LeguRi but here's why that's BS.  There is no "opposition to changes," and there is no one who an act of rebellion will impress.  People are talking about games they want to talk about.  Will him deleting cause some 4e'er to say "You're right, I've seen the light, I'll play OD&D?"  No.  The mods and some veteran community members totally agree, we need more non-4e coverage.  There is NO ONE who is working against this.  This is a logical fallacy - since it's not happening, "summun must be agin' it!!!"  It's easy for people to want action from others to fix it, but only action from you will.

Comment: @mxyzplk: Waaah, I'm taking my ball and going home.

Comment: Your wish is my command.

Comment: I get where JUST is coming from. Myself, I have few questions to ask—I can't cause the change I want to see, because I can generate precious few non–D&D-4e questions to shift the trend. I'm here to think about and answer interesting questions from people, and I don't really get to do that much. And it's not quite correct to say that it will impact nobody—from where I sit, seeing users who are interested in non–D&D-4e games leaving indicates that there will be fewer interesting questions in the future. (Not arguing anything, to be clear—just throwing some more grist into the mill for everyone.)

Comment: What's ironic is that his gesture will mostly be seen only by other people who have decided on the same course of action and want to know how to do it! Talk about preaching to the converted...